# How do I remove only one element from an array from Redux? Not working for me currently

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I am trying to make a simple algorithm to delete an item from an array. It should be dynamic.

Reducer:

```js
import { LOAD_PAGES, REMOVE_PAGE } from "./dynamicMenuActions";

export const initialState = { pages: [] };

export const dynamicMenuReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_PAGES:
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: [...state.pages, action.pages]
      };
    case REMOVE_PAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: [...state.pages.filter((p, i) => p.dataIndex !== action.pages[i].dataIndex)]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default dynamicMenuReducer;
```

The action:

```js
export const removePageAction = (pages) => ({
  pages,
  type: REMOVE_PAGE
});
```

So in the component I call it like this:

```js
  const deletePage = () => {
    const pagesCopy = [...props.pages];

    removePageAction(pagesCopy);
  };

  return (
        {!!props.pages.length &&
          props.pages.map((p, index) => {
            const inputValue = get(inputsValue, `${p.pageType + index}`, "") || p.name;
            return (
              <Nav.Item key={index}>
                {editing.isSet && p.dataIndex === editing.data ? (
                  <>
                    <input
                      value={inputValue}
                      name={p.pageType + index}
                      onChange={handleInputsChange}
                    />
                    <Button onClick={() => toggleEdit(p.pageType + index, false)}>
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <Button size="sm" variant="link" onClick={() => deletePage()}>
                      X
                    </Button>
                  </>
                )}
              </Nav.Item>
            );
          })}

  )
```

This is how the pages array looks like:

```
pages: [{
  name: "page name",
  editable: true,
  pageType: "page type",
  dataIndex: "dataIndex"
}]
```

Right now it deletes all of the items in the array instead of just one.

Can you see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only pass in the deletePage action the index of the page to be deleted and not all the pages. Right now it deletes all the pages because because you pass in the all the pages in `removePageAction`

```
import { LOAD_PAGES, REMOVE_PAGE } from "./dynamicMenuActions";

export const initialState = { pages: [] };

export const dynamicMenuReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_PAGES:
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: [...state.pages, action.pages]
      };
    case REMOVE_PAGE:
      return {
        ...state,
        pages: [...state.pages.slice(0, action.index), ...state.pages.slice(action.index + 1)]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default dynamicMenuReducer;
```

--
Action

```
export const removePageAction = (index) => ({
  index,
  type: REMOVE_PAGE
});
```

Component

```
const deletePage = (index) => {

    removePageAction(index);
  };

  return (
        {!!pages.length &&
          pages.map((p, index) => {
            const inputValue = get(inputsValue, `${p.pageType + index}`, "") || p.name;
            return (
              <Nav.Item key={index}>
                {editing.isSet && p.dataIndex === editing.data ? (
                  <>
                    <input
                      value={inputValue}
                      name={p.pageType + index}
                      onChange={handleInputsChange}
                    />
                    <Button onClick={() => toggleEdit(p.pageType + index, false)}>
                      Edit
                    </Button>
                  </>
                ) : (
                  <>
                    <Button size="sm" variant="link" onClick={() => deletePage(index)}>
                      X
                    </Button>
                  </>
                )}
              </Nav.Item>
            );
          })}

  )
```

Comment: Mmm in this case `p.dataIndex !== action.index`, the data `p.dataIndex`  is not an index number. It is something like: `p.dataIndex === GeneralPage1`

Comment: I updated my code for a different approach using index

Answer (score 0):

Modify your action so that you can apply filter.

export const removePageAction = index => ({
  index,
  type: REMOVE_PAGE
});